# Django- MultiValueDictKeyError while requesting GET object from html page

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I am having a problem while fetching the data from HTML.

**In views.py**

```
def PrimeNumber(request):
    number = request.GET['number']
    return render(request , 'PrimeNumber.html',{'number':number})
```

**In html file**

```
<form action = "{% url 'PrimeNumber' %}">
    <label for="number"><b>Enter the number : </b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Number" name= "number" required>
</form>
```

***Error I am facing***

> Exception Type:   MultiValueDictKeyError
>   Exception Value:"'number'"

I dont what is happening over here. Since I am beginner in python I have gone through many answers on stackoverflow but did not understand how to implement that on my own code.
Please inform if any information is missing.

Comment: `request.GET` is a QueryDict (similar to a python dictionary, except it can hold multiple values for the same key, hence `MultiValueDict`), so accessing a key that isn't in the dictionary raises a KeyError. If you want to access a key you're not sure is present, you should use the `get` or `getlist` methods: `request.GET.get('somekey')` which returns `None` if the key isn't present. You can also change `None` to a default value: `request.GET.get('somekey', 'empty')` would give the string 'empty' if 'somekey' isn't present.

Comment: Now why 'number' isn't present I'm not quite sure. But it looks like you're using the same view for rendering your empty html form the first time and for when you're submitting it. I guess the error happens before you even submit your form?

Answer (score 3):

Change your fetching `number` method same as:

```
number = request.GET.get('number')
```

And if you want default value if `'number'` not passed, use below line:

```
number = request.GET.get('number', 0)
```

**Attention:** `request.GET.get('number')` return `None` if this parameter not find on the `request.GET` and default value not set.

Comment: After implementing the source given by you, when I try to enter the number in the text box and click the prime number URL then it is showing me that 'you have entered the number:: ' None. (Wish I can add the screenshot). 
I mean, it is not fetching the number which I am entering in the text box and comes up with None as a value.

Comment: @SahilNagpal are you sure that "number" parameter sent to server and are you sure that you used GET method for sending data to server? **annotate:** `request.GET.get('number')` return None if this parameter not found on the request.GET

Comment: I forgot to say a big thanks for helping me. 
Yes M.J I have a parameter 'number' sent to the server.
As mention in HTML file
<form action = "{% url 'PrimeNumber' %}">
<label for="number"><b>Enter the number : </b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Number" name= "number" required>
</form>
There is the name number which I am fetching in get request

Comment: You don't set form method and by default form method is POST, replace all `request.GET` in your code by `request.POST`

Comment: after setting it to request.post I am having the ''QueryDict' object is not callable' error.
This is the  code now
number = request.POST('number')


    return render(request , 'PrimeNumber.html',{'number': number})

Comment: @SahilNagpal `request.POST`  is not a function :|  You must use `request.POST.get` instead

Comment: Tried and still getting none as a value :(

Comment: In this tag: `<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Number" name= "number" required>`, Remove space between  `name=` and "number"...
Your question is about request.GET... your code is buggy and we not here to trace and debug your code

Comment: Space here does not seem to any sort of error or bug here. I have removed that but still getting the same none as value.

Comment: Ok, test request.GET.get('number') now... I think your browser default method is GET

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181920/discussion-between-sahil-nagpal-and-m-j).

Comment: Okay, lets go to chatroom